# Insert into python list. Check if entry still exists

Tags: python

I have many equal URL's with and without 'www'.
My csv file looks like that:

```
www.first.com
first.com
www.second.com
second.com
www.third.eu
third.eu
forth.tr
fifth.com
...`
```

I iterate over the list, fetch the ip address and insert them into a dict.
How can I remove (or check before inserting) the duplicate (with www) entries?

My expected result is:

```
[{'entry': ['first.com', '192.168.31.101'},
 {'entry': ['second.com', '192.168.31.102'},
 {'entry': ['third.eu', '192.168.31.103'},
 {'entry': ['forth.tr', '192.168.31.104'},
 {'entry': ['fifth.com', '192.168.31.105'}]


with open('myfile.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    result = []

    for row in reader:
        addr = socket.gethostbyname(row[0])
        result.append({'entry':[row[0], addr]})
```

Comment: Just something to keep in mind -- Some hosts may not respond to requests both ways. I ran into this issue where some servers would not respond to requests for the domain without the `www.` -- and vice-versa

Answer (score 3):

Use a set to determine if an IP address has not been seen before. If the address is unknown, add it to the set and store the record.

And strip the 'www.' from the url if you want to store the base url.

```
adresses = set()
for row in reader:
    addr = socket.gethostbyname(row[0])
    if addr not in adresses:
        adresses.add(addr)
        url = row[0][4:] if row[0].startswith('www.') else row[0]
        result.append({'entry':[url, addr]})
```

Answer (score 1):

First you want to remove the 'www' if there is one.  Then you can check if it's in the dictionary using "if address in dict:".  That is:

```
with open('myfile.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    result = []

    for row in reader:
        addr = socket.gethostbyname(row[0])
        if addr[:4] == "www.":
            addr = addr[4:]
        add = True
        for item in result.values():
            if addr == item[0]:
                add = False
                break
        if add:
            result.append({'entry':[row[0], addr]})
```

Comment: Your test 'not (addr in result)' will always evaluate to True.

Comment: I don't think so; it should only evaluate to False if addr is, in fact, already in result, which I believe is the point.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Still not :) You compare the IP adress to the items in the `result` list. But these items are dictionaries. The values of the dicts are lists and the second value in such a list is the IP address that we're looking for.

The structure of `result` is something like `[{'x':['a',1]}, {'x':['b',2]}]`and we check if there's already a 1 or 2 in the list.

Comment: Fair enough.  That last edit should do it.  Sorry for wasting your time; your answer above is clearly superior

Answer (score 0):

You can test if it's in the dictionary by doing

```
url = url.replace("www.","")
url = url.replace("http://","")
url = url.split("/")[0]
if url in my_dict:
    pass
else:
    my_dict[url] = ip_address
```

Comment: I can change the dict format to {Key1:Value1, Key2:Value}. Thats not the problem..
My problem is: 
'first.com' is already in the dict.
How can I prevent that www.first.com will be inserted in the dict?

Comment: Just do replace("www.",""). If you want to account for stuff like http:// you can either include that in a series of replaces or you can use regex.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have a list of dictionaries containing a single item?  Why not just use one dictionary?  It would look like this with the first two entries:

```
url_dict = {'first.com':'192.168.31.101', 'second.com':'192.168.31.102'}
```

If you wish to check if a url containing www is already in the dict:

```
if url[:4] == 'www.':
    if url[4:] in url_dict.keys():
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehensions: ( the inner loop will iterate once every outer iteration to replace the 'www' )

```
 with open('myfile.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
       reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
       result = {h: socket.gethostbyname(h) for w in reader (w.replace('www.', '') for w in h) if result and h not in result.keys()}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason to have all those 'entry' keys?

It's more reasonable to have such dictionary:

```
entry = {'url': 'ip'}
```

Then your code could be:

```
import csv
import socket

with open('myfile.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    entry = {}

    for row in reader:
        for url in row:
            addr = socket.gethostbyname(url)
            url = url.replace('www.', '')  # get rid of www.
            if not(url in entry):  # if key is not already in dict
                entry[url] = addr
```

And your entry dict looks after that like:

```
{'google.com': '173.194.122.240', 'youtube.com': '173.194.73.190'}
```